# pythonにてIOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directoryと表示され、手詰まりになる

Tags: python

python、というかプログラミング初心者です。
ご回答頂けたら幸いです。

以下のコードをテキストエディタ(メモ帳)に書いた後、デスクトップの
自分のフォルダにmymod.pyという名前で保存しました。

```
def countLines(name):
file = open(name)
return len(file.readlines())
```

そして、IDLE (Python GUI)にて以下の方法で起動しようとしたら、

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\c-file")
>>> import mymod
>>> mymod.test('mymod.py')
```

以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
  mymod.test('mymod.py')
 File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\c-file\mymod.py", line 9, in test
  return countLines(name) , countChars(name)
 File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\c-file\mymod.py", line 2, in countLines
  file = open(name)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mymod.py'
```

このエラーの意味するところ、そして対処法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
ちなみに使用しているのはPython2.7.11です。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `<` `>` などの記号が含まれていると意図しない表示になることがあるので、その場合ソースコードでなくてもコードブロックで整形するとよいです。というわけでエラー文をコードブロックで整形し、改行とインデントも復元してみましたが、 mymod.py の中身もインデントが失われていませんか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！
my.modの中身のコードですが、こちらのインデント忘れは、質問時の編集ミスでした、わかりにくい質問してしまい、申し訳ないです。

Answer (score 4):

以下の状況と推測します。

1. Python IDLE はWindowsのスタートメニューなど（コマンドライン以外）から起動している

   -> 起動直後の状態はおそらく、カレントディレクトリがPythonのインストールディレクトリとなっています。以下のコードで確認出来ます:

   ```
   >>> import os
   >>> print(os.getcwd())
   ```
2. `mymod.py` を保存したディレクトリは `"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\c-file"`

   `file = open(name)` は `file = open('mymod.py')` として解釈されます。このとき、
   カレントディレクトリにある `'mymod.py'` ファイルを開こうとします。

上記の結果、Pythonをインストールしたディレクトリに mymod.py ファイルは無いため、 `No such file or directory` (そんなファイル無いよ）というエラーになります。対処方法としては以下のいずれかがあります。

A. `os.chdir("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\c-file")` を先に実行しておく。
B. 開くファイルを絶対パスで指定する。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
対処方法を実行してみたところ、無事ファイルが開かれることが確認できました。
ご回答頂きありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

> No such file or directory: 'mymod.py'

は`mymod.py`という「ファイルがない」という意味です。
<del>notepadではデフォルトでは`.txt`という拡張子で保存するので、

本当に`mymod.py`で保存されているか`mymod.py.txt`で保存されていないか確認してみて下さい。（エクスプローラーの状態によっては拡張子が表示されないモードになっている場合があります）</del>
あと、カレントディレクトリはファイルのあるディレクトリになっていますか？
フルパスに変えて実行してみて下さい。

あと、

```
def countLines(name):
    file = open(name)
    return len(file.readlines())
```

のようにインデントが必要で、
`>>> mymod.countLines('mymod.py')`
のように呼び出す必要があると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ファイルについてですが、mymod.pyで保存されていることが確認出来ました。
また、インデントに関しては、こちらの質問時の編集ミスです。
分かりにくい質問になってしまったかもしれません。
申し訳ないです。